# Architecture and design patterns for components

Tags: game-design, architecture, design-patterns, entity-component-system

I was working on a physics-based plug-in/ extension for Unity water which would essentially be another component in Unity water.

The goal of this extension would be to integrate interactive physics between a solid body and the water (taking an object as the parameter as this component is to be integrated into the Water object).

The question is, before implementation, I wanted to come up with a high-level architecture of the system and I was looking for suggestions on that. I've considered general game design but this is more of a component and mostly code so I'm not sure how game design principles fit into that.

I am therefore, looking for a recommendation on the approach for the design of this system. Low level design using class diagrams and sequence diagrams or a high-level overview using ECS or alternative techniques?

Please let me know if something is unclear in my question and needs further clarification.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what specific goals this system is trying to serve or problems it's trying to solve, so that makes it difficult to make concrete recommendations of patterns suitable for solving those problems / serving those goals. As currently phrased, it would be difficult to answer this question with more than opinion. Can you try editing your post to explain the problem you're solving in more concrete detail?

Comment: I've edited my question. Hope that brings some clarity.